# How to update database.. .mdf is read only after deployment

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, deployment

I have created a Windows application and created setup for it and then installed on Windows 7.

In this setup the `.mdf` SQL Server database file become read only when the installer has installed in target machine. So when I have started the application it was able to read the file but not able to modify/ add data in Windows 7 environment but when I have the same application installed on Windows XP, it is working perfectly. The installer has installed same copy of file as it is not become read only.

So kindly provide me information how I can create setup for WindowS 7 OS for `.mdf` file.

Comment: did you use **Advanced Installer** to generate the setup file ? if so, you can add full control on database files.

Comment: also check this [link](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/183758/Failed-to-update-mdf-database-because-the-database).

Comment: its not working, any other method when setup file making time or any??

Comment: and i dont use advanced installer